# How to determine which CPU a thread runs on?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

Is there a way to determine on which CPU a given thread runs on?
Preferably in C#, but C++ would do.

The .NET Process and ProcessThread classes don't seem to provide this information.

ETA Clarifications:

We are developing a server application that processes http multicast streams and spawns multiple video encoders. This runs on a system with 12 physical cores, resulting in 24 logical CPUs (hyperthreading). Via TaskManager and ProcessExplorer we have verified that our spawned processes spread evenly over the logical CPUs. However, we are seeing a lot of (kernel?) activity on just one CPU that interferes by eating up unusual amounts of CPU time. We are trying to identify which process(es)/thread(s) are running on this particular CPU. Neither TaskManager nor ProcessExplorer seem to provide that information. If they do, please explain how such information can be obtained.

Otherwise, we are contemplating writing our own tool to get this information. And that is what we need help with.

We know how to change a threads affinity (and we know that there is no guarantee that a thread will remain associated with any CPU, although in this particular case the thread(s) eating up CPU remain associated with only one CPU), but in order to do so, we need to first determine WHICH process/thread needs to be relocated. That is the sole objective of this question.

I hope this helps clarifying the issue.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this information?

Comment: It is known to the kernal only. So you need to program in kernal mode. Look for Kernal APIs on MSDN.

Comment: What would you want it to do if a thread ran on many different CPUs at different times?

Comment: On some operating systems (e.g. Linux) it may happen that a given thread is migrated from one CPU core to another one. So why do you ask?

Comment: You can search for "thread affinity", but in general this information won't help much...

Comment: If you profile it using visual studio you can see it. Most time it doesn't change.

Comment: We are running a complex application on a system with 12 cores. For reasons we need to find out we are seeing spiked CPU usage on only one core. We want to find out which threads (and thereby which processes or services) are running on this particular core. We don't know of a tool that gives that information and contemplating writing one of our own.

Comment: @Harald: Cool, a genuine legitimate use!

Comment: @Harald: ProcExp provides that information. It even provides thread stack. However a thread does not have any association with a CPU unless it's running at the moment. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: Not avalid quesstion. This is not about which CPU - it is about why the heck this supposeidly multi threaded program does not use more than one cpu. Check thread load in a proper profiler and you may see that you have a processing bottleneck. Visual Studio has ap profiler for this type of analysis.

Comment: What about driver activity? I'm not sure these days how interrupts are assigned to cores. Is there any driver that is particularly wound-up by your app?

Comment: If you actually have a process/thread that is not migrated among cores then you probably have a process (or thread) that has a specific core affinity. If Process Explorer shows that it is your application using the CPU (it will show you the process that uses the most CPU on the core) then look in your application for something that request process affinity. Your use case seems suspect to me.

Comment: Try piping your output to dev\null. I wonder if the kernel work is the TCP/IP stack.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx), using the ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity property you can *set* the thread affinity, but you cannot get it. By default threads have no affinity (can operate on any processor).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessThreadIdealProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Make sure there is an instance of notepad running.
            Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (notepads.Length == 0)
                Process.Start("notepad");
            ProcessThreadCollection threads;
            //Process[] notepads;
            // Retrieve the Notepad processes.
            notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            // Get the ProcessThread collection for the first instance
            threads = notepads[0].Threads;
            // Set the properties on the first ProcessThread in the collection
            threads[0].IdealProcessor = 0;
            threads[0].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly `Thread.SetProcessorAffinity` does the same thing.

Comment: In addition, threads ARE moved around, so even if you would get an answer it would not necessarily be valid the moment you try to check something.

Comment: Yeah, the ProcessorAffinity properties on Process and ProcessThread were my first hope, but as you pointed out, I can't GET it...

Comment: @TomTom: yes, they can be moved, but in our case a snapshot would already provide valuable information.

Comment: @Harald implicitly if you set the processor affinity you know what it is. Is it a third party component you are using which you need to know the affinity for?

Comment: Yes, most likely. We are developing a server application that processes multicast streams and spawns multiple video encoders. Our spawned processes spread evenly over the cores but we're seeing a lot of (kernel?) activity on just one core that interferes. We need to identify what exactly it is that interferes in order to fix it.

Comment: @Harald have you tried using third party profiling applications like JetBrains dotTrace (highly recommended) or ANTS Profiler? http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: @ Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson: Good suggestion. We are certain that the encoding processes we spawn spread evenly over the cores (and the 24 logical CPUs (incl. hyperthreading)). They are the only ones running that could explain the loads on the cores. Process Explorer confirms that. We just can't explain why one of the 24 logical CPUs shows such an extra load. But profiling could certainly help to rule out our app.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do in a continuous reliable way. OS task scheduler optimises threads and splits load between available CPU cores. In general case a thread can be executed on any CPU. Moreover with context switches it can also change it's CPU.

If you need to pin-point specific a thread or a process you can only assign its affinity, so you can have reasonable hope that the process/thread will be executed on a particular logical CPU.

Comment: Although technically correct, you answer is missing very important point. Knowing your current CPU can **dramatically** reduce contention by bucketing the shared resource. Yes, in rare cases you will be interrupted and moved to other core. This means that synch is still needed. But the perf results are incomparable.

Comment: @KirillKobelev can you please give me some refs for this. I can see it working on a low level, but not sure how you can manage this from an application. Are you talking about NUMA?

Comment: Think about performance of `int cnt[num_cores]; InterlockedIncrement(cnt[GetCurrCore()]);` vs simple version with just one counter.

Comment: Similar sharding (as explained above) can be done on a managed thread ID. Anyway, I came to this question wondering if such could also be done on (initiation) CPU core #. Guess not so easily.. sharding by managed ID is still very useful in some cases to significantly reduce lock contention.

Answer (score 1):

Since Vista/Server2003, you can PInvoke the `GetCurrentProcessorNumber()` Windows API method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessornumber).

Obviously Windows-only, so not ideal if you plan to support other platforms.

I'm not sure the OP's use case was ideal, but where it might be sensible/useful is when trying to create a timestamp that is guaranteed unique within a system, even if all processors are computing one at exactly the same time.