# Is there a way to see which threads are using which CPUs in an application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a heavily multi-threaded C# .NET app that runs on a box with 16 cores.  I would like to see (in code), which CPU a specific thread is running on.  Specifically, I'd like to glean this information from inside the thread.

Anyway to do that?

Comment: Which CPU, or which core? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998895/how-to-determine-which-cpu-a-thread-runs-on, though it doesn't seem like an exact duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 0):

On the x86/64 platform, the CPUID instruction can return this information (which core the thread is currently executing on) - I don't know off hand if that is exposed already in the .NET framework, but you could call out to an unmanaged DLL function to return the information.