# Threads can run on different processors or cores for both Task.Factory.StartNew and Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am looking to clarify my understanding of .NET multithreading, and in particular, which .NET methods create threads which may potentially execute at the same time on different processors or cores in a multi-processor/core system.

In the .NET TPL framework you can use the methods Parallel.Invoke, or Task.Factory.StartNew to achieve some kind of parallelism.

My understanding is that in both cases .NET creates new Tasks (behind the scenes for Parallel.Invoke), which the .NET environment then allocates to managed threads behind the scenes, which are then assigned to threads, which the CPU may allocate to different cores or processors depending on the workload. The main difference between the two methods is semantics - Parallel.Invoke executes multiple tasks and waits for them to complete; Task.Factory.StartNew starts a new task in the background. In both cases, the actual work may be done on different cores or processors. As per [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).

I have a colleague who is convinced that only the Parallel.Invoke method allows the threads to be executed on different cores/processors, and that Task.Factory.StartNew starts a new thread but that thread will only be scheduled on one core/processor - so doesn't actually give parallelism.

I can't find any documentation or articles which explicitly state whether this is the case or not. My colleague refers me to the same articles that I am looking at, such as [Task-based Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming), which I think validate my understanding but my colleague thinks validates his.

The documentation sometimes uses the term "parallel processing" with reference to Parallel.Invoke and "asynchronous tasks" with reference to "Task.Factory.StartNew", but as far as I understand the same thing happens in the background with regards to allocation to multiple processors/cores.

Can anyone please help to clarify the situation, if possible with links to documentation/articles.

I know this sounds like seeking resolution to an argument with a colleague, but I am genuinely looking to clarify whether or not I understand this correctly.

Comment: Firstly, your colleague is wrong. Secondly, as a life tip - don't spend time trying to prove incorrect colleagues wrong. Ask them to provide evidence of their point of view instead - shift the burden of proof to them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine which CPU a thread runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998895/how-to-determine-which-cpu-a-thread-runs-on)

Comment: Refer your opponent to the .NET source code, both [Parallel.Invoke](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,2a071ae7cdd05c58) and [Task.Factory.StartNew](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,fb6e45941d931629) are there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy to answer.

[Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool  ....

[Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

> ...  In addition, the TPL handles the partitioning of the work, the scheduling of threads on the ThreadPool, ....

Using the same ThreadPool how is it possible for the ThreadPool to determine the type of task in order to limit the CPU?  Either they both run on all Processors or the they all run one a Single Processor.

Extra Credit:

This begs the question, *Is the ThreadPool Multi-Core aware*?

The answer is surprisingly, it doesn't care.  The [ThreadPool asks the operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343/how-do-i-spawn-threads-on-different-cpu-cores) (just like any c# application that uses `new Thread()`) for a Thread, it actually the responsibility of the OS. I think it would be pretty clear by now that with all the abstraction that even suggesting that C# can **by default** limit how threads are used is a pretty ridiculous assertion.  (Yes you can run a thread on whatever core you want etc etc, but that is not how the ThreadPool works by *default*).

I highly recommend reading [StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)... TLDR?  Use `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score 0):

Although operating systems sometimes provide for "processor affinity," this is an edge-case and its use (or availability) is quite rare.  So far as I am aware, .NET does *not* make any use of such things.

Your foundation assumption must always be:  "a runnable thread/process will run where it damn well pleases," and it might switch from one CPU resource to another at any time.  The .NET framework makes things a whole lot "nicer" for you in a lot of ways, but the underlying scheduling decisions are still being made – exclusively – by the host operating system.